# Fetch data from public API using dynamic url

Tags: javascript

I want to fetch data from this public API which takes a parameter. I would like to then display this fetched data in a table.
I also have two buttons backwards and forward which change the parameter for the URL and therefore display a new set of data in the table.

The forward button adds 1 to the parameter and the backwards button substracts 1 from the parameter of the API url.

This is my current code:

HTML code:

```
    <div align="center">
  <button style="display:inline" onclick="backFunc();">Back</button>
  <p id="gameweek" style="display:inline;"></p>
  <button style="display:inline" onclick="forwardFunc();">Forward</button>
  <br>
  <br>
      <table id = "fixtures_table">
      <tbody id ="tbody"></tbody>
      </table>
</div>
```

This is my javascript code:

```
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.withCredentials = true;

    var urlparam = "1";
    roundnum = 0;
    var gameweek;

    request.open("GET", "https://api-football- 
    v1.p.rapidapi.com/v2/fixtures/league/524/Regular_Season_-_" + urlparam);
    request.setRequestHeader("x-rapidapi-host", "api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com");
    request.setRequestHeader("x-rapidapi-key", 
    "733394c196mshc5cdb3fe20f1ec5p162525jsnc81f4950b7d6");

    var data 

    request.onload = function () {

    data = JSON.parse(this.response);

    gameweek = document.getElementById('gameweek');

    gameweek.innerHTML = data.api.fixtures[roundnum].round;

    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {

    var tbody = document.getElementById('tbody');

    var table = document.getElementById('fixtures_table');

    data.api.fixtures.forEach(fixtures => {

        var tr = document.createElement('tr');

        tr.innerHTML = '<td>' + fixtures.homeTeam.team_name + '</td>' + 
        '<td>' + fixtures.goalsHomeTeam + '</td>' + 
        '<td>' + "VS" + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + fixtures.awayTeam.team_name + '</td>' + 
        '<td>' + fixtures.goalsAwayTeam + '</td>' + 
        '<td>' + fixtures.status;

        tbody.appendChild(tr);
        table.appendChild(tbody);

        });
}

console.log(data);
}
function forwardFunc(){
}
function backFunc(){
}
```

However I am not sure how to make the forward and backwards function fetch the new set of data using the updated parameter and display those results in the table instead of the old ones.